# Is it a good experience to open a browser on browser

Tags: interaction-design, experience, use-cases

I recently came up with an idea of opening a browser on a browser.
I had a use case where I show multiple news from different publishers on a page.
But when clicked it opens in a new tab on a mobile device and it's very hard to get back to the same previous page.

So is it possible to open the same link as a pop-up on the same screen?

Is there any example of this kind of use case and Can this be done?

Main use case for me is it is a painful process for user to get back to the 
previous screen after going to a new window in mobile.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You mean like an 'open in new window' but a "squeezed" window?

I've not seen this done before, but I can imagine some pros and cons.

---

### **Pros:**

- It would keep the user oriented, in knowing which page they've come from.
- They can easily hop back to the original site.

---

### **Cons:**

- It will reduce the real estate for the page content. Mobile devices already have limited screen space.
- What if the user opens a browser on a browser, like you suggested, but then opens a browser on that browser and then a browser on that browser and then.... **infinite regression**.

[image]

---

I would say the whilst in some cases it might be nice so you don't lose the original page,  the cons are too difficult to maneuver around to make this a viable option.

Comment: I agree, but what if we show a near article on a browser by disabling address bar? In this case we can limit user to enter that infinite browsers loop

Comment: Main use case for me is it is a painful process for user to get back to the previous screen after going to a new window in mobile

Comment: By disabling the address bar you're restricting the users browsing freedom, i'm not sure it's the right solution. I resonate with you there is a painful process in there somewhere because the back button will take you to the previous, but it will also close the current tab.

Comment: But there is no back button in IOS and my use case there was to show user the news when he clicks on the news link and I am doing it by showing it in overlay .

Comment: I would say that the problem you have identified there is pretty key to the question, rather than a comment. hint hint